# Trapezoid and angle bisectors

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The angle bisectors of $\measuredangle BAD$ and $\measuredangle ADC$ of the trapezoid $ABCD$ $(AB\parallel CD)$ intersect at $O$. Find the lengths of $AD$ and $DC$ if $\cos\measuredangle BAD=\dfrac23,OC=\sqrt7,OB=3\sqrt{15}$ and $AB=5DC$.

[image]

The only thing I was able to gather is that $\measuredangle AOD=90^\circ$ as $$\measuredangle DAO+\measuredangle ADO=\dfrac12\measuredangle BAD+\dfrac12\measuredangle ADC=\dfrac12(\measuredangle BAD+\measuredangle ADC)=\dfrac12 180^\circ=90^\circ\\\Rightarrow \measuredangle AOD=90^\circ$$ I don't see how I can use the given lengths as for example in triangle $BOC$ we have only 2 elements. And of course we can say $DC=x\Rightarrow AB=5x$.

Comment: Find cosines of $BAO$, $CDO$. Mark $AD=y$, $DC=x$, $AB=5x$. Express $DO$ in terms of $y$. Write cosine rule for $CO$ and $BO$. Then solve system of two equations for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, thank you for the response! How can I find the cosine of $BAO$?

Comment: Cosine of BAO can be found by the half angle formula.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu, thank you! We have $\cos\measuredangle ADC=-\cos\measuredangle BAD=-\frac23$. How do we know if $\measuredangle CDO$ is acute or obtuse?

Comment: $DO$ is angle bisector, then $\angle CDO=\frac{1}{2}\angle ADC < 90°$

Comment: Moreover $\angle CDO=90°-\angle OAB$, $\cos CDO=\sin BAO$ and you can use half angle formula for $\sin BAO$.

Answer (score 2):

You have already established that $\angle AOD=90^o$. Let $DC=x, AB=5x$ and $AD=y$.

If $\angle OAD=\theta$. then $\cos2\theta=\frac23\implies2\cos^2\theta-1=\frac23$
$$\implies\cos\theta=\sqrt{\frac56}\implies \cos(90-\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$$

Therefore, $OD=\frac{y}{\sqrt{6}}$ and $AO=y\sqrt{\frac56}$

Now apply the Cosine Rule in triangles $ODC$ and $OAB$ giving
$$7=\frac{y^2}{6}+x^2-\frac13 xy$$
and$$135=25x^2+\frac56y^2-\frac{25}{3}xy$$

Multiplying the first of these equations by $25$ and subtracting gives
$$40=\frac{10}{3}y^2\implies y=2\sqrt{3}$$
Substituting this back into the first equation gives
$$x^2-\frac23\sqrt{3}x-5=0\implies x=\frac53\sqrt{3}$$